# Login Error Form IRS For A2A MeFClientSDK000049: Private key not found in KeyStore file for alias

Tags: java, mef, irs

**Name of Service Call:** Login

**Message ID of Service Call**: 471922016077bw85rjjb

**Transaction Result**:

> gov.irs.mef.exception.ToolkitRuntimeException: MeFClientSDK000033: Message level security error;
>
> gov.irs.mef.services.msi.LoginSecurityHeaderHandler; handleMessage(); com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException:
>
> gov.irs.mef.exception.ToolkitRuntimeException: MeFClientSDK000049: Private key not found in KeyStore file for alias.;
>
> gov.irs.mef.services.msi.LoginSecurityEnvironmentHandler;

**certificatpath.jks;** **aliace**

Answer (score 1):

maybe OP has fixed this, but for anyone else arriving to this post,

that error means that the certificate needed to connect to the mef system was not found... in other words

verify that the app.config is pointing to the correct location of the trusted certificate, and that it is actually installed on the machine

in my case, i had to place it under "MY" and LocalMachine, and also the FindByThumbprint value must be the same as in your certificate, with that it should work

sometimes i saw that i got this error  despite the certificate being correctly installed, and it happened because i tried to reinstall more than 1 the same certificate, so i would just remove it, then install it, and everything worked. hope this helps future google searches